# get text area and text field data - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 text areas in my page as;

```
<input type="text" id="a1"/>
<textarea id="b2"></textarea>
<a id="button">button</a>
```

When user click the button link, I want to `alert` the data entered in `a1` and `b2`.

How can I do this?? Here is there **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k9kYR/)**

Thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert($('#a1').val());
      alert($('#b2').val());
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use same id `a1` for `<a id="button">button</a>` and `<input type="text" id="a1"/>`

and you can use jquery `val()` function to get value

```
alert($('#a1').val());
alert($('#b2').val());
```

Answer (score -2):

Do like this :

```
window.alert($("#a1").val());
window.alert($("#a2").val());
```

Your code should appear likt this :

```
<input type="text" id="a1"/>
<textarea id="b2"></textarea>
<a id="button" onclick="window.alert($('#a1').val());window.alert($('#a2').val());return false;">button</a>
```